# Getting a run time error when running docker container with ASP .Net core 3.1 web service

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have no problem to run in my local, but I got a run time error when running a Docker container --

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Actually I can see System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.2.2.0 in Dependencies/Frameworks folder, why Docker can't load this file when container is running?